# Firebase - How would I go through a list of urls and store them in a JS list?

Tags: javascript, database, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I have a list of URLs in my firebase database which I need to get in my JS. They are structured like this:

```
Name : "1" Value : "https://something.com"
Name : "2" Value : "https://google.com"
```

How would I convert that to something I can use in JS to which I can say "Give me the second value" and have the second value?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this:

First add an `<input>` element with `type="text"`, and a button, then `onclick` of a button you can retrieve the value of the `<input>`

```
var value = document.getElementById('inputvalue').value;
```

and use the `value` in the query:

```
orderByChild("Name").equalTo(value)
```

---

```
firebase.database().ref().child("Urls").orderByChild("Name").equalTo(value).on('value').then(function(snapshot) {
snapshot.forEach(function(child) {
var childData = child.val();
var value=child.val().Name;
var urlvalue=child.val().Value;
 )};
)};
```

Assuming you have this in the database:

```
Urls
 pushid
    Name: 1
    Value: "https://something.com"
 pushid
    Name: 2
    Value: "https://google.com"
```

This way if the user wrote "2" in the text field you will be able to retrieve that value and the url from the database.